# вычислить последовательность

Tags: c#, алгоритм

n = 12
должно вывести 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0)+(1+1)+(1+2)
Написал 2 программы, но пишет, из-за того что долго выполняются - процесс отменяется. То есть, их нужно оптимизировать, только вот КАК
Код двух программ:

```
using System;

public class TwistedSum
{
public static long Solution(long n)
{
int res = 0;
int ostatok = 0;
int Part = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
      if (i >=10)
      {
      Part = i;
      while (Part >= 0)
      {

          ostatok = Part % 10;
          Part = Part / 10;
          res = res + ostatok;
      }
      }
      else { res = res + i}
   }

  return res;
}
}
```

(тут передается в n число, все нормально, просто только функция написана)
2ой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace codewarsSumaCifr
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long n = 10;
        Console.Write(Solution(n));
        Console.ReadKey();

    }


    public static long Solution(long n)
    {
        int res = 0;
        string str2 = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                str2 = str2 + i.ToString();
            }

        for (int j = 0; j < str2.Length; j++)
            {
                res = res + (int)Char.GetNumericValue(str2[j]);

            }
        return res;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Было бы очень неплохо описать что же за последовательности вы ищите, а то сейчас вам напишут if (n == 12){printf(что вам надо);}

Comment: передается к примеру n = 10, мне нужно вернуть 46, то есть 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0) // = 46

Comment: задания на codewars предназначены для самостоятельного выполнения.

Comment: @PashaPash я понимаю, но код у меня, "можно сказать написан верно", дело только в том, что он выполняется слишком долго, для codewars

Comment: @Илья потому что суть заданий codewars - придумать быстрое И оригинальное решение. а не просто решить влоб.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Цикл, вообще не правильное решение, его надо свернуть, и решить задачу аналитически. Решать задачу целиком скучно, но идею, как она решается, подкину:

```
9:    (0+0)+(0+1)+(0+2)+(0+3)+(0+4)+(0+5)+(0+6)+(0+7)+(0+8)+(0+9) = 45
19:   (1+0)+(1+1)                          ... +(1+8)+(1+9) + 45  = 1*10 + 1*45 + 45
29:   (2+0)+(2+1)                 ... +(2+8)+(2+9) + 2*45 + 1*10  = 2*10 + 1*10 + 2*45 + 45
...
99:   (9+0)+(9+1)  ...+(9+9) + 9*45 + 8*10 ... + 1*10 = 9*10 + 8*10 ... + 1*10 + 9*45 + 45
```

Comment: Такое решение лучше, да, но я не уверен, что отсюда можно найти *аналитическое решение*: скорее всего какой-то цикл  все таки нужен. Если найдете аналитическое решение, очень хочу знать, и [стоит добавить его в описании в OEIS.](http://oeis.org/A037123).

Comment: @PeterOlson, мне все таки кажется что аналитическое решение есть, сейчас нет особо времени и сил копаться в этом, но позже, когда "разгребусь по работе" попытаюсь вспомнить что я там учил в своем институте и поискать это аналитическое решение, но не сегодня и скорее даже не в этом месяце :(

Answer (score 5):

Придумал алгоритм, который вычислит намного быстрее. [Вычислительная сложность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) [предыдущего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442588/176684) — `O(n log(n))`, тогда так сложность этого ответа — `O(log(n))`.  Вот код, объяснение ниже. Процесс примерно так, как и [в ответве Mirdin'a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442627/176684).

```
public static long Solution(long n)
{
    long sum = 0;
    long power = 1;
    while (power <= n)
    {
        long mod = n % (power * 10),
            remainder = (n - mod) / 10,
            digit = mod / power;

        sum += 45 * remainder +
            power * digit * (digit - 1) / 2 +
            digit * ((mod % power) + 1);

        power *= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

### Как это работает?

Например, как узнать `Solution(62345)`? Считаем по каждой цифре:

- 6234**5**: `(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)*6234 + (0+1+2+3+4) + 5`
- 623**4***5*: `(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)*6230 + (0+1+2+3)*10 + 4*(5+1)`
- 62**3***45*: `(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)*6200 + (0+1+2)*100 + 3*(45+1)`
- 6**2***345*: `(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)*6000 + (0+1)*1000 + 2*(345+1)`
- **6***2345*: `(0+1+2+3+4+5)*10000 + 6*(2345+1)`

Ещё замечаем, что `0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9` равно `45`, и что `0+1+...+(k-1)`равно `k*(k-1)/2`:

- 6234**5**: `45*6234 + (5*4/2) + 5`
- 623**4***5*: `45*6230 + (4*3/2)*10 + 4*(5+1)`
- 62**3***45*: `45*6200 + (3*2/2)*100 + 3*(45+1)`
- 6**2***345*: `45*6000 + (2*1/2)*1000 + 2*(345+1)`
- **6***2345*: `(6*5/2)*10000 + 6*(2345+1)`

В сумме, получится 1276185.

Comment: Кстати, в вашей же ссылке на OEIS было готовое решение: `a(n) = (1/2)*((n+1)*(n-18*sum{k>0,floor(n/10^k)})+9*sum{k>0,(1+floor(n/10^k= ))*floor(n/10^k)*10^k}).`

Comment: @PashaPash Ах да, я это как-то пропустил, не очень внимательно посмотрел ограничение суммы.

Answer (score 1):

Первая программа почти правильное, только у вас бесконечный цикл `while (Part >= 0)`. Можно делать так, немного по проще:

```
public static long Solution(long n)
{
    long sum = 0;
    for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        long j = i;
        while (j > 0)
        {
            sum += j % 10;
            j /= 10;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Кстати, это [последовательность A037123 в OEIS](http://oeis.org/A037123).

Comment: да, спасибо. Ваша программа работает, но все равно выдает: Process was terminated. It took longer than 6000ms to complete

Comment: попробуйте while(j > 10) программа не работает потому что сколько на 10 не дели 0 не получишь.

Comment: @Илья С каким выводом? Очень большое число?

Comment: В n передаются такие числа как: 12345, 123456, 1234567, 12345678, а если попробовать while(j>10), то если передать к примеру n=3, оно выведет 0, а надо 6) @PeterOlson

Comment: @OlegUP Не понимаю вас, функция работает, я пробовал.  `while(j > 10)` пропустит много чисел.

Comment: @Илья До 12345678 вычисляется довольно быстро, а 123456789 уже нет.

Comment: @PeterOlson оно передает одновременно 123, 1234, 12345, 123456, 1234567, 12345678. Если интересно, вот задание на codewars http://www.codewars.com/kata/527e4141bb2ea5ea4f00072f/train

Comment: @PeterOlson не так выразился. Не одновременно, а по очереди, считает для каждого числа

Answer (score 0):

У вас бесконечный цикл. `while (Part >= 0)` при том, что `Part` инициализируется 1, а потом ее можно очень долго делить на 10, всегда будет больше 0

**UPD** `Part = Part / 10;` Всегда будет больше 0, и из цикла `while (Part >= 0)` вы никогда не выйдете.

Comment: Код часто редактировал, поэтому так получилось, у меня там if(i>=10) else { просто суммирует i}, но все равно пишет, что очень долго

Comment: Эм, либо поправьте пример актуальным кодом, либо у ват там все-таки бесконечный while в первой программе, и никакая проверка на I его не спасет.

Comment: в общем я понял, либо бесконечность получится, либо у меня первую цифру в числе всегда будет отбрасывать. Дальше не знаю как написать)

Comment: скорее всего, вы не так выразились, если долго делить на 10, он не всегда будет "больше 0", а равен нулю будет всегда :)

Comment: ну да, там же int...

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё один рекурсивный вариант, проходящий по цифрам, с мемоизацией. Вычислительная сложность также должна быть по идее логарифмическая.

```
// вспомогательная функция: сумма цифр
static int SumOfDigits(int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        result += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

// главная функция
public static int F(int n)
{
    // выход из рекурсии для чисел меньше 10
    if (n < 10)
        return F1(n);

    int result = 0;

    // обрабатываем по одной цифре справа налево
    // для маски 10000 текущее число будет иметь форму xyz..t0000
    for (int mask = 1; n > 0; mask *= 10)
    {
        // выбираем число t0000
        int lastPart = n % (mask * 10);
        // делим его на цифру и степень
        result += FDigitTimesPowerOfTen(lastPart / mask, mask);

        // убираем обработанную цифру
        n -= lastPart;
        // компенсация: на каждом числе из убранной части
        // нужно добавить цифры остатка
        result += lastPart * SumOfDigits(n);
    }

    return result;
}

// вычисление функции для числа вида t00000
// в этом случае digit = t, mask = 10000 (степень десятки)
static int FDigitTimesPowerOfTen(int digit, int mask)
{
    if (digit == 0)
        return 0;
    // заменяем все старшие цифры на 0
    // при этом для компенсации добавляем 1000...0 раз убранные цифры
    // то есть F1(digit - 1)
    return FPowerOfTen(mask) * digit + F1(digit - 1) * mask;
}

// кэш для степеней десятки
static Dictionary<int, int> FPowerOfTenCache = new Dictionary<int, int>(100) { { 1, 1 } };
// вычисление функции для степеней десятки
static int FPowerOfTen(int n)
{
    int result;
    if (!FPowerOfTenCache.TryGetValue(n, out result))
    {
        // n-1 имеет на одну цифру меньше, спускаемся рекурсивно
        result = 1 + F(n - 1);
        FPowerOfTenCache[n] = result;
    }
    return result;
}

// функция для одноцифрового числа - сумма арифметической прогрессии
static int F1(int n)
{
    Debug.Assert(0 <= n && n < 10);
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
```